# How to fetch latest timestamp values from table using DynamoDB PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB.
In my application, every registered user has some sensors on his account and those sensors will send some data every 5 mins to our database.

Now I want to show "If user has logged into his account, I should need to display all his sensors with latest timestamp values for each sensor".

I did this with three queries like "I fetched all devices under his account -> Original sensor IDs -> each sensor latest value " so this process taking very long time to execute.

And my tables look like this:

users:

```
---------------------
|sno  | userId      |
---------------------
| 1   | naveenkumar |
|--------------------
| 2   | abc         |
|--------------------
| 3   | xyz         |
|--------------------
```

sensor_devices:

```
---------------------
| id | sensorId     |
---------------------
| 1  | sensor1      |
|--------------------
| 2  | sensor2      |
|--------------------
| 3  | sensor3      |
|--------------------
| 4  | sensor4      |
---------------------
| 5  | sensor5      |
---------------------
```

And

users-sensors:

```
----------------------
| userId | sensorId  |
----------------------
| 1      |  1        |
|---------------------
| 1      |  2        |
|---------------------
| 1      |  4        |
|---------------------
| 2      |  5        |
|---------------------
```

data_tbl:

```
---------------------------------------------
| sensorId  | value    | timestamp          |
---------------------------------------------
| sensor1   | 4.3      | 2014-01-21 11:21:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor2   | 5.0      | 2014-01-21 11:22:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor3   | 10.0     | 2014-01-21 11:19:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor4   | 6.3      | 2014-01-21 11:25:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor1   | 8.3      | 2014-01-21 11:26:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor2   | 6.0      | 2014-01-21 11:27:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor3   | 9.0      | 2014-01-21 11:24:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor4   | 6.3      | 2014-01-21 11:30:00|
|--------------------------------------------
```

And Final Output table which will see the user in his homepage:

```
---------------------------------------------
| sensorId  | value    | timestamp          |
---------------------------------------------
| sensor1   | 8.3      | 2014-01-21 11:26:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor2   | 6.0      | 2014-01-21 11:27:00|
|--------------------------------------------
| sensor4   | 6.3      | 2014-01-21 11:30:00|
|--------------------------------------------
```

And my query looks like this and it's taking long time to execute, so please provide me a better solution:

Let us assume $_SESSION['login_id'] = 1;

```
<?php
  $aws = Aws::factory('config.php');
  $client = $aws->get("dynamodb");

  $tableName = "data_tbl";
  echo "<table border=1>";
  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<th>Sensor ID</th>";
  echo "<th>value</th>";
  echo "<th>Timestamp</th>";
  echo "</tr>";

  //Query to get user devices
  $devices = $client->query(array(
    "TableName" => "users-sensors",
    "KeyConditions" => array(
      "userId" => array(
        "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
        "AttributeValueList" => array(
          array(Type::STRING => $_SESSION['login_id'])
        )
      )
    )
  ));
  foreach ($devices['Items'] AS $key=>$value) {
    $id = $value['sensorId']['S'];
    //Query to get original sensorId from sensor serial number
    $device = $client->query(array(
      "TableName" => "sensor_devices",
      "KeyConditions" => array(
        "id" => array(
          "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
          "AttributeValueList" => array(
            array(Type::STRING => $id)
          )
        )
      )
    ));
    $dids =  $device['Items'][0]['sensorId'][Type::STRING];
    //Query to get all latest values of sensors
    $response = $client->query(array(
      "TableName" => $tableName,
      "KeyConditions" => array(
        "sensorId" => array(
          "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
          "AttributeValueList" => array(
            array(Type::STRING => $dids)
          )
        )
      ),
      "Select" => "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES",
      "AttributesToGet" => array("sensorId","value","timestamp"),
      "ScanIndexForward" => false,
      "Limit" => 1  
    ));
    foreach ($response['Items'] AS $key=>$value) {
      echo "<tr>";
      $link = "graph.php?id=".$id;
      echo "<td><a href='$link'>".$value['sensorId']['S']."</a></td>";
      echo "<td><a href='$link'>".$value['value']['S']."</a></td>";
      $epoch = $value['timestamp']['S'];
      $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $epoch);
      echo "<td><a href='$link'>".$timestamp."</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

If I would get answer for this I would get complete my job.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You're looking at and thinking of DynamoDB from a relational database perspective.  DynamoDB is **not** a relational database.  You (generally) don't want to model your data in DynamoDB like you would in MySQL.  Like just about anything in software development/computer science, this is a tradeoff. You pay some data de-normalization and duplication costs in exchange for extremely low query latency and extreme scalability.

I don't use PHP, so I can't help you with the code, but I think I can help you with your data model design.

If I understand your requirements correctly, need to get a list of sensor IDs and their latest timestamps for each user upon user login.  If so, here is one potential approach you could take to reduce your queries from 3 to 1:

Your table's hash key is `UserID` and the range key is the `Timestamp` of the sensor event:

```
------------------------
| Hash Key | Range Key |
------------------------
| User ID  | Timestamp |
------------------------
```

The table would have an attribute of `Sensor ID` corresponding to which sensor observed the event.  An entry for User `12` observed  by sensor `29` on February 14, 2014 at 11:51 AM could look like this:

```
---------------------------------------
| Hash Key | Range Key     | Sensor ID |
----------------------------------------
|    12    | 1392396884000 |    29     |
----------------------------------------
```

Note that I used the timestamp in milliseconds so that DynamoDB could easily sort it.

Now, when a user logs in, you can query the table by `User ID` to get every event for that user.  In your query request, set the `ScanIndexForward => false` (from the DynamoDBSDK docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_query).  DynamoDB will return your results in order from most recent to least recent.  If there are a large number of events for that user, DynamoDB will page the result set accordingly, but you can see how to handle that in the DynamoDB documentation.

Now you have a list (or whatever the corresponding data structure in PHP is) of events for that user.  You'll need to filter by `SensorID` to get the most recent.  The good news is that since the results are in order, you can just iterate through the results and check the `Sensor ID` of each item; if you do not have a result from that `Sensor ID`, add it to your filtered collection.  If you've allready added an event from that `Sensor ID`, that means you have the most recent event from that `Sensor ID` for that `User ID` and you should skip it.

Depending on the needs of your application, if you needed to get a list of every event for the sensors, you could simply put a global secondary index on the table using an index hash key of `Sensor ID` and the event `Timestamp`.  Since the `User ID` is part of the primary key of the table, DynamoDB will automatically project it into the index.

Hope that helps.